# How to do a for loop in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field called Weeks. I have created a Number of Weeks parameter of:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

When the user selects a Number of Weeks parameter, the for loop should filter the week data.

For example:
Number of Week 2 has been selected

```
Week = Max(Week) or Week = Max(Week)-1
```

I would want to dynamically do the filter with a for loop. How can this be achieved in Tableau?

Thanks

Comment: Tableau doesn't have control loops like for/while/do etc.  What are you trying to accomplish?  There is probably a more "Tableau" way to do it.

Comment: I would like the user to be able to choose how many week he wants to display. For example: Selects 10, the most recent 10 weeks in the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, this is very easy.

Create a calculated field that is `[Weeks]<=[Number of Weeks]`.  Put this field on the filter shelf and select the value of true.

Any weeks that are less then the parameter selection will remain in the viz.

No for loop necessary!

---

New answer:

Here is a generic approach for this.  Create a calculated field with the formula `index()`.  This lets you assign a value to each row.  Put it on the rows shelf, set it as Discrete, and move it to the left of all other dimensions (assuming a table here).

Then create another calculated field `[your index field] <= [Number of Weeks]` and put it on the filter shelf and set to True.  You can uncheck 'Show Headers' on the index calculated field to hide it.

In my picture Week 1 lines up with line 1 but it will work for your scenario, too.

[image: Week filter]

Comment: Weeks are for example 1,2,3,4,5,6. Number of Weeks is 2,3,4,5,6. It won't work. The number of weeks is how much I want to display from the latest.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!!